# Is it possible to do custom display of members in Flex Builder variables view?

Tags: debugging, flexbuilder

Is it possible to display something other than the definition name in the variables view in Flex Builder for special types?

Basically, what I'd like to do is display the value of a complex member type instead of just showing it's qualified type name. Take a look at the following image:
[image: Flex Builder variables view]
<sub>(source: [brightworks.com](http://www.brightworks.com/flex_ability/wp-content/uploads/2006/09/var_view_image.jpg))</sub>

In the second column you can see the value of the member in the first column. What I'd like to to is to somehow make Flex Builder write an arbitrary string instead of foo.bar.MyClass (@0123456), is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a configuration setting in FlexBuilder (that I know of) so the only way I can think of to do it would be to replace whatever Java classes in Flex Builder plugin that deal with the variables pane and the debug output with custom ones that you've written to do what you are looking for.  Since it's closed source it would have to be a clean room implementation, which would be tough.  I've seen some examples of people replacing the java classes in Flex Builder to fix bugs ([example](http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2009/09/29/flex-builder-3-on-eclipse-3-5/?utm_campaign=BackType&utm_medium=bt.io-twitter&utm_source=&utm_content=backtype-tweetcount)) so it's not impossible to do if you have the time and knowledge.